# force log off after UAC has been disabled

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, uac, logoff

I'm having to install Windows updates on multiple stand alone systems. I have my update_script.bat script to run, but as it loops through installing each update I am prompted by UAC controls for my credentials. So I found a command line option to turn off UAC.

```
@echo off

echo Disabling UAC controls...

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

shutdown /l /f
```

This way when I pass my scripts out to my subordinate admins, they can quickly run the first script; it'll automatically log them off then they can execute the second script (update_script.bat) file, but the problem I am having is when I test the first script to turn off UAC, the command window stops at:

---

Disabling UAC controls...

The operation completed successfully.

c:\updates>

---

instead of completing and forcefully logging the user off.

How do I get the system/script to force log off after I disable UAC controls?

Comment: Why `cmd /k`? Can't you run reg.exe on its own?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not a script guru. I pulled that command from another forum - 3rd post from the bottom: http://superuser.com/questions/227860/how-to-toggling-uac-on-off-quickly-eg-using-command-line-in-windows-7

And you are probably right. I probably can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k
```

from the batch file.

Running `cmd.exe` will start a new command prompt, which is usually not what you want within a batch file.